# panic: open templates/base.html: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: google-app-engine, go

With shadynasty.biz/blog/2012/07/30/quick-and-clean-in-go link I am Trying to Create template in go programming. My project Structure is created with the Go-SDK google app engine. google_appengine/myapp/hello/hello.go file is present, then where to create template folder? I created the "template" folder in "hello" folder but getting error **"panic: open templates/base.html: The system cannot find the path specified"** and server stops running. What can be done?

Comment: For Example :                                                                   package main

import( "fmt"
  "net/http"
   "html/template"
  
 )

var index = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
  "/templates/base.html",
  "/templates/index.html",
))

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
 if err := index.Execute(w, nil); err != nil {
      http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
  }
 
 fmt.Fprint(w, "hello", "\n")  
 
}


func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using template on appengine is only posible if you pass the html from field, because of appengine rules you dont have access to the filesystem

here is an example

```
const loginTemplateHTML = `<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
      <div><input name="username" type="text" /></div>
      <div><input name="password" type="password" /></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="login"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
    `    
var loginTemplate = template.Must(template.New("Login").Parse(loginTemplateHTML))

func login (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := loginTemplate.Execute(w,nil); err != nil {
         http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we do the same thing with "template" method? With http://shadynasty.biz/blog/2012/07/30/quick-and-clean-in-go/ link I was trying the example but it was giving "panic: open templates/base.html: The system cannot find the path specified" this error. Where should I place "templates" folder ? directory is google_appengine/myapp/hello/hello.go and google_appengine/myapp/hello/templates/base.html and index.html Example: var index = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
 "templates/_base.html",
 "templates/index.html",
))

Comment: as i sad, on appengine, you **can't** use templates from folder, **you have to put them in the code as const or var**

but if you just do the complete example from link, i guess you have to put the templates folder under myapp directory

Comment: Ok. Able to view the basic content from template now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually you do have access to almost any file you put to your application folder.

You could use the ioutil to read the files:
http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile

And a point to note, you can only read files not specified by the static handler in app.yaml.

So, keep your template files in one folder and your static and directly served files in another folder.

Comment: How do you specify the template files to upload in `app.yaml`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is app engine does not call your application like go run hello.go. It calls from the root directory go run google_appengine/myapp/hello/hello.go. You have two solutions to fixed this problem.

1. Redefine the paths to be called from the root directory.

What I recommend and verified works is just setting adding the path from the root of the project to the template folder. For example, if the root of the project is myRepo/ and the path to the webapp is /myRepo/webapp/hello.go, then the template is now at webapp/templates/index.html instead of templates/index.html. In order to call it similar to app engine, you will call it from the root directory. go run webapp/main.go.

2. Define a custom entrypoint in the app.yaml.

I have not verified this solutions yet, but I think it will work. In the app.yaml, there is a entrypoint command is the command use to startup the code.

entrypoint: cd myRepo/webapp/ && go run main.go

Here is the documentation for app.yaml. Make sure add urls for your static dir.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref